# Convert json multidimensional to array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I would like to convert Json data to an array  Javascript, that I can access like using array[0][0], someone can help me please.

```
[
    {
        "Login": "test1",
        "Nom": "test1",
        "Prenom": "test1p",
        "password": "124564",
        "Email": "test1@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "Login": "test2",
        "Nom": "test2",
        "Prenom": "test2p",
        "password": "124564",
        "Email": "test2@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

I tried this piece of code but nothing happen , I can't access to a specific(Exemple I would like to have Nom) data in array using for example array[0][1].

Code.js

```
var data = [
    {
        "Login": "test1",
        "Nom": "test1",
        "Prenom": "test1p",
        "password": "1267846",
        "Email": "test1@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "Login": "test2",
        "Nom": "test2",
        "Prenom": "test2p",
        "password": "124494",
        "Email": "test2@gmail.com"
    }
];

function data_to_array(data) {
    var array = [];
    for (var key in data) {
        var value = data[key];
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            array[key] = value;
        } else {
            array[key] = data_to_array(value);
        }
    }
    return array;
}

var array = data_to_array(data);
for(var i in array)
    console.log(array[i]);
```

Once parsed, if I try to access it using myArr[0][1], it shows as undefined.

Comment: Definitely you are doing it wrong. Never use `for..in` with an array. What is the expected output?

Comment: Why don't you simple use `for (var i=0,......`

Comment: But `data` is not JSON, it is itself an array. What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = [];

for (var i=0, len=data.length, tmp; i<len; i++) {
  tmp = [];
  for (var k in data[i]) {
    if (data[i].hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      tmp.push(data[i][k]);
    }
  }
  arr.push(tmp);
}

arr;
// [
//   ["test1","test1","test1p","124564","test1@gmail.com"],
//   ["test2","test2","test2p","124564","test2@gmail.com"]
// ]
```

If you can rely on es5 functions, you can use Array.prototype.map and Object.keys

```
var arr = data.map(function(e) {
  return Object.keys(e).map(function(k) { return e[k]; });
});

arr;
// [
//   ["test1","test1","test1p","124564","test1@gmail.com"],
//   ["test2","test2","test2p","124564","test2@gmail.com"]
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have confused with the array and objects. All arrays are objects. but not all objects are arrays. You use "for..in" loop in wrong understanding on array containing objects.
If you add more console statements and check, you can understand how it works. Let me give reqd. solution for your scenario.

```
var data = [
    {
        "Login": "test1",
        "Nom": "test1",
        "Prenom": "test1p",
        "password": "1267846",
        "Email": "test1@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "Login": "test2",
        "Nom": "test2",
        "Prenom": "test2p",
        "password": "124494",
        "Email": "test2@gmail.com"
    }
];

function data_to_array(data) {
    var array = [];
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        var obj = data[i];
        array[i] = new Array();
        for(var key in obj) {
            array[i].push(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return array;
}

var array = data_to_array(data);
console.log(array);
```